# Configuring Excel File for Automatic Content Activation

Tags: excel, visual-studio, ssas-tabular

I'm currently working on an Excel file that includes external links to my CUBE. Within my cube, there's a Row-Level Security (RLS) function implemented to ensure that a manager can only view data related to their squad.

What I'm aiming for is to have my Excel file update automatically upon opening. I have configured this in my file, but when shared with others, the "Enable Content" security pop-up prevents the file from updating automatically and applying the data filtering for each manager.

Is there a workaround for this issue? For instance, is there a way to delay displaying data until the file is updated, or are there any alternative solutions that don't involve using VBA? Any guidance on resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[This post describes the same issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1561133/refresh-data-when-opening-the-file-option-not-working-on-excel-pivot-table) regarding the enable content prompt halting an update. The comment below is the answer given that provided links on how to setup the trust center.

"Connections to external data may be currently disabled on your computer. To refresh the data when you open a workbook, you must enable the data connections by using the Trust Center bar, or you must place the workbook in a trusted location. For more information, [see Add, remove, or modify a trusted location for your files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-in-microsoft-office-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4), [Add, remove, or view a trusted publisher](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-remove-or-view-a-trusted-publisher-87b3d5a3-b68c-4023-87c4-7cc78a44d7ed), and [View my options and settings in the Trust Center](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-my-privacy-options-in-the-microsoft-office-trust-center-d672876e-20d3-4ad3-a178-343d044e05c8)."

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately, none of the provided solutions is suitable for my situation. Modifying settings, such as removing security protections from my file, only affects my access and doesn't resolve the issue when the file is shared. Additionally, adding new trusted paths to the base is ineffective since my file is shared through our SSRS, resulting in other users encountering pop-up prompts.